# How can i get role_id from this array

Tags: laravel

I am trying to get the role_id BUT i do not know how to do it because it does not work:

Auth::user->roles()->role_id

object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#843 (1)

{ ["items":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(App\Role)#839 (23) { ["table":protected]=> string(5) "roles" ["connection":protected]=> NULL ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(2) "id" ["perPage":protected]=> int(15) ["incrementing"]=> bool(true) ["timestamps"]=> bool(true) ["attributes":protected]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "6" ["role_title"]=> string(11) "FaceInicial" ["role_slug"]=> string(11) "faceinicial" } ["original":protected]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> string(1) "6" ["role_title"]=> string(11) "FaceInicial" ["role_slug"]=> string(11) "faceinicial" ["pivot_user_id"]=> string(2) "15" ["pivot_role_id"]=> string(1) "6" } ["relations":protected]=> array(1) { ["pivot"]=> object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot)#841 (26) { ["parent":protected]=> object(App\User)#817 (24) { ["table":protected]=> string(5) "users" ["fillable":protected]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(4) "name" [1]=> string(5) "email" [2]=> string(8) "password" [3]=> string(8) "username" } ["hidden":protected]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(8) "password" [1]=> string(14) "remember_token" } ["connection":protected]=> NULL ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(2) "id" ["perPage":protected]=> int(15) ["incrementing"]=> bool(true) ["timestamps"]=> bool(true) ["attributes":protected]=> array(9) { ["id"]=> string(2) "15" ["name"]=> string(13) "administrador" ["email"]=> string(13) "test@test.com" ["password"]=> string(60) "$2y$10$mC/LOcYzv3akuC1nFYawdOEzDINJq9pyVl8Ej4vY1XlcWfnODbkQy" ["remember_token"]=> string(60) "o2PV91bkFAAHYUjgy9Yd8ZIRtXgdrapByVLgeuWklcaKbSL0QAXtIvY4PQ6C" ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2018-10-15 11:27:42" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2019-02-11 13:13:49" ["username"]=> string(13) "administrador" ["deleted_at"]=> NULL } ["original":protected]=> array(9) { ["id"]=> string(2) "15" ["name"]=> string(13) "administrador" ["email"]=> string(13) "test@test.com" ["password"]=> string(60) "$2y$10$mC/LOcYzv3akuC1nFYawdOEzDINJq9pyVl8Ej4vY1XlcWfnODbkQy" ["remember_token"]=> string(60) "o2PV91bkFAAHYUjgy9Yd8ZIRtXgdrapByVLgeuWklcaKbSL0QAXtIvY4PQ6C" ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2018-10-15 11:27:42" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2019-02-11 13:13:49" ["username"]=> string(13) "administrador" ["deleted_at"]=> NULL } ["relations":protected]=> array(0) { } ["visible":protected]=> array(0) { } ["appends":protected]=> array(0) { } ["guarded":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "*" } ["dates":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dateFormat":protected]=> NULL ["casts":protected]=> array(0) { } ["touches":protected]=> array(0) { } ["observables":protected]=> array(0) { } ["with":protected]=> array(0) { } ["morphClass":protected]=> NULL ["exists"]=> bool(true) ["wasRecentlyCreated"]=> bool(false) ["forceDeleting":protected]=> bool(false) } ["foreignKey":protected]=> string(7) "user_id" ["otherKey":protected]=> string(7) "role_id" ["guarded":protected]=> array(0) { } ["connection":protected]=> NULL ["table":protected]=> string(9) "role_user" ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(2) "id" ["perPage":protected]=> int(15) ["incrementing"]=> bool(true) ["timestamps"]=> bool(false) ["attributes":protected]=> array(2) { ["user_id"]=> string(2) "15" ["role_id"]=> string(1) "6" } ["original":protected]=> array(2) { ["user_id"]=> string(2) "15" ["role_id"]=> string(1) "6" } ["relations":protected]=> array(0) { } ["hidden":protected]=> array(0) { } ["visible":protected]=> array(0) { } ["appends":protected]=> array(0) { } ["fillable":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dates":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dateFormat":protected]=> NULL ["casts":protected]=> array(0) { } ["touches":protected]=> array(0) { } ["observables":protected]=> array(0) { } ["with":protected]=> array(0) { } ["morphClass":protected]=> NULL ["exists"]=> bool(true) ["wasRecentlyCreated"]=> bool(false) } } ["hidden":protected]=> array(0) { } ["visible":protected]=> array(0) { } ["appends":protected]=> array(0) { } ["fillable":protected]=> array(0) { } ["guarded":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "*" } ["dates":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dateFormat":protected]=> NULL ["casts":protected]=> array(0) { } ["touches":protected]=> array(0) { } ["observables":protected]=> array(0) { } ["with":protected]=> array(0) { } ["morphClass":protected]=> NULL ["exists"]=> bool(true) ["wasRecentlyCreated"]=> bool(false) } } }

Comment: It's pretty difficult to read here. What does `Auth::user->roles` or `Auth::user->roles()` return? It seems like `->roles()` return a collection, which means you can't simply run `$collection->id`. If this works, then you can use map to achieve what you want: Auth::user->roles->each(function($item) { var_dump($item->role_id` });

Comment: Please try to format your code, its impossible to read this way, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the below solution.

```
$user = \Auth::user();
$name=$user->name;
$roles = $user->getRoles();
```

**OR**

You can try this:

```
Auth::user()->roles[0]->id
```

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getRoles();

Comment: @InversionesCovaCodesCA Is roles a pivot table? How is your relationship setup in User model?

Comment: I am using /**
     * Many-To-Many Relationship Method for accessing the User->roles
     *
     * @return QueryBuilder Object
     */
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
    }

Comment: @InversionesCovaCodesCA: Please check my updated answer

Comment: Thank you very much !! @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd, it worked Auth::user()->roles[0]->id

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, this should return what you want

`Auth::user()->roles()->pluck('id')` (or `role_id`, it's pretty difficult to read in above chunk)

If it does, in your User model, you can write

```
public function getRoles() {
   return $this->roles()->pluck('id')
}
```

And then,

`Auth::user()->getRoles();`

Answer (score 0):

Your log message is impossible to read but I see what wrong with your code.

You can't get attribute from array, you can only get it from single collection, so you have to select which collection you want, in my example I select `first()` one (with laravel special method).

```
Auth::user->roles()->first()->role_id;
```

Or you can do it with normal php way

```
Auth::user->roles[0]['role_id'];
```

note: you have to use `roles` in second example, you can't use `roles()` because it will return `Relations`(`BelongsToMany` in your case) class not collection